# Enabling an extension on a Three.js shader

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, three.js

How can I enable an extension on a Three.js shader?

My code so far:

getting extension:

```
var domElement = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
var gl = domElement.getContext('webgl') || domElement.getContext('experimental-webgl');
gl.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives');
```

on my shader:

```
fragmentShader: [
    "#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable",
    "code..."
]...
```

The console output:
WARNING: 0:26: extension 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' is not supported
ERROR: 0:32: 'dFdx' : no matching overloaded function found 
ERROR: 0:32: '=' :  cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to '2-component vector of float'
ERROR: 0:33: 'dFdy' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:33: '=' :  cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to '2-component vector of float'

After reading [this issue on github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1621), I tried this example: From http://jsfiddle.net/VJca4/ I get these errors

WARNING: 0:27: extension 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' is not supported
ERROR: 0:30: '=' :  cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to '2-component vector of float'
ERROR: 0:31: 'dFdx' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:31: '=' :  cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to '2-component vector of float'

Comment: jsfiddle had missing vec2, and three.js was too old - see http://jsfiddle.net/VJca4/9/ it totally works )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should also be able to do this:

```js
renderer.context.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives');
```

Comment: How did you put this into use? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: I also have this problem. I'm calling `renderer.context.getExtension('GL_OES_standard_derivatives');` but I get `ERROR: 0:114: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is disabled` when I try to create a `ShaderMaterial` from my shader code. If I compile the shader in regular webgl with `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable` on the first line, it works.

Comment: It seems the way to do this in the current three.js codebase is to set `derivatives = true` in the `ShaderMaterial` on creation.

Comment: MyShaderMaterial.extensions.derivatives = true; as of r88

Answer (score 3):

Found the error. You have to use the renderer's dom element:

```
var gl = renderer.domElement.getContext('webgl') ||
            renderer.domElement.getContext('experimental-webgl');
gl.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives');
```