# Create topography/contour lines with GLSL - WebGL

Tags: glsl, webgl

I want to slice horizontal contour lines through a geometry similar to the process described in this post - [How to create latitudinal (horizontal) contour lines in GLSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891763/how-to-create-latitudinal-horizontal-contour-lines-in-glsl)

I'm doing this with WebGL, and it seems that "fwidth" is only available for OpenGL. Is there an available workaround so that I can get the anti-aliasing from fwidth on the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fwidth function is available using WebGL, you just have to use the [OES_standard_derivatives extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_standard_derivatives/) by running:

```
var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_standard_derivatives");
if (!ext) {
  // tell user they can't use your site or provide
  // other fallback
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Here's is the reference for THREEjs users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071693/enabling-an-extension-on-a-three-js-shader